# continue rebase after `git rebase --abort` and origin remove

Tags: git, git-rebase

I added a new remote to my repo. Then I executed `git reset --hard d3d52cee3cf112f30bd4a19611ed34e025d10120` to force `HEAD` to reset and it worked. I continue working. After other actions, I tried to push my work to origin but it failed. When I try to fix things up I create conflicts and before fixing them I do `git rebase --abort` and loose everything I commited in between. How can I get back everything that I did before run command `git rebase --abort`?

Here is pretty much everything I did:

```
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git push origin master
^C
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remote add origin 
https://hellomustaq@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravel2.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remote -v
origin  https://sazaldhaka@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravelbackend.git 
(fetch)
origin  https://sazaldhaka@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravelbackend.git 
(push)
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remove rm origin
git: 'remove' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
remote
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remote rm origin
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remote add origin 
https://hellomustaq@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravel2.git
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git add .
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git commit -m "draft"
[master 7afb7d9] draft
6 files changed, 238 insertions(+), 89 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 resources/views/table.blade.php
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git status
On branch master
fatal: Could not open file .git/rebase-merge/done for reading: No such 
file or directory
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git remote -v
origin  https://hellomustaq@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravel2.git 
(fetch)
origin  https://hellomustaq@bitbucket.org/mobilelili/laravel2.git 
(push)
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $  rebase --abort
rebase: command not found
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git  rebase --abort
mustaq@Dell /opt/lampp/htdocs/wee $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry . i edited my question. how can i get back everything what i did before run commend git rebase --abort and newly add repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to list the commits that `HEAD` has pointed to. There you can find the commit before your `git rebase --abort` and you can force your `HEAD` to return to it.

Example:

```
$ git reflog
a9646cd HEAD@{0}: rebase: aborting
4821905 HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout test
a9646cd HEAD@{2}: commit: 3
177bb91 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from test to master
4821905 HEAD@{4}: commit: 2
177bb91 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to test
177bb91 HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): 1

$ git reset --hard 4821905
HEAD is now at 4821905 2
```